# Unzip -l in python

Tags: python, unzip

Is there a way to list all files within a zipped archive in Python? Under bash I usually use   `unzip -l myzip.zip`
thanks for any hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the list returned by [`ZipFile.infolist()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist).

Answer (score 2):

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(path) as f:
  for name in f.namelist():
    print name
```